# Create New Record statement on Record Next button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to add an if clause on one of my buttons.

I have the general "Cycle Next" button running VBA on most of my user forms, but my users have a habit of using it to create a new record instead of using the "New Record" button.

Is there any way to check if they're on the last record & if so, create a new record using my call "New Record" VBA?

I have specific VBA that runs on the "New Record" button that needs to be added to the form & they spam the "Cycle Next" button creating 3-4 unnecessary new records. I'll probably add a message box that tells them they're creating a new record to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *OnCurrent* event of the form:

```vb
Me!CycleNextButton.Enabled = (Me.CurrentRecord <> Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount)
```

Comment: awesome, that does work, but i do have a question on how i would be able to incorporate calling a sub to setup the new record if it's true & if not just continue the rest of the OnCurrent Event?

Comment: actually, i found a way to incorporate it i think. I do appreciate the help